# How to append elements of an R list to each other, but only the top level?

Tags: r, list, stack, append, melt

I need to append lists contained inside a top-level list. Other levels should be preserved, and there should be more than 2 elements possible.

```
l <- list(list(1:5), list(6:10))
required <- c(l[[1]], l[[2]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** We can `flatten` with `c` from `base R`

```
do.call(c, l)
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

#[[2]]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

**2)** Or with `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE`.  Also a `base R` solution

```
unlist(l, recursive = FALSE)
```

---

**3)** Or with `lapply` (`base R`)

```
lapply(l, unlist, recursive = FALSE)
```

---

**4)** Or using `Map` (another `base R`)

```
Map(c, l)
```

---

**5)** Or with `flatten` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
flatten(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `mapply()`:

```
#Code
mapply(c,l)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or also `lapply()`:

```
#Code 2
lapply(l,unlist)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or `sapply()`:

```
#Code 3
sapply(l,c)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

All `base R` solutions.

Comment: this is perhaps a sequential loop; 10% more time-consuming on average